# Behaviour of oleophobic and hydrophobic object in an oil and water solution

Tags: water, solutions, materials

I am wondering what would happen if I put a small (between $\mathrm{5mm}$ and $\mathrm{1\mu}$, density between $\mathrm{1}$ and $\mathrm{2\: g/mL}$) item with both oleophobic and hydrophobic properties into an oil and water solution. Does anybody know? Would the item become suspended between the oil and water layers? I have not been able to find the answer anywhere!